# Uploading an image using Multer in a Node.js, Typescript and typeORM project using service, controller model

Tags: node.js, typescript, postman, typeorm, multer

I will be very specific with this one. I am trying to upload an image for Staff entity in my project but the error persists. Here is my code snippets -->

```
//from typeORM 

@Column({default : ""})
image!: string;
```

```
//Staff Service
  static async postImage(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const staffData = new Staff()
      staffData.image = req.file?.path ?? "Some value here"
      await staffRepository.save(staffData)
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "Image for staff added to database",
        data: staffData
      })
      console.log("Image uploaded", staffData)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error creating staff:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
  }
```

```
// Staff Controller
 // image staff
  static async postImage(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
   StaffService.postImage(req,res)
  }
```

```
// middleware and route -->
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, "./public/temp")
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
      cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix)
    cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
  })
  export const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

// Staff Image Request defined here -->
routesStaff.post(`${pathConstant.pathPreFixStaff}/upload`),upload.single("image")
StaffController.postImage
```

I want to post image via different route but it should be added in the Staff create form , but currently its not working in Postman itself, when i hit the route it says "Not found", I am confused as to where the error is.